# Disable accelerator table items in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to temporarily disable a few items from an accelerator table when the input focus is on a CEdit field.

My application has some commands associated with keyboard keys (A, S, D, etc.) and I need to disable those while the user is entering text in the field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [CopyAcceleratorTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646364(v=VS.85).aspx) to get the ARRAY of ACCEL structures then edit out the ones you don't want, Call [DEstroyAcceleratorTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646368(v=VS.85).aspx) on the current table.  Then use [CreateAcceleratorTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646365(v=VS.85).aspx) to create the new table with the edited accelerator table.

Edit: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646337(v=VS.85).aspx#editable_acc) link may be useful.

Comment: I used this method and it worked well. Just a short note on how to obtain the correct HACCEL in a CFrameWnd (derrived) MFC class: 

this->m_hAccelTable

; To get an arbitrary HACCEL use: LoadAccelerators(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(YOUR_RESOURCE_ID));

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Goz works very fine. To save all other people some time, here is sample code that follows his suggestion:

```
// Allocate the accelerator buffer
HACCEL hAccelOld = LoadAccelerators(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_ACC_TECONTROL));
int iNumAccelerators = CopyAcceleratorTable(hAccelOld, NULL, 0);   
ACCEL *pAccels = new ACCEL[iNumAccelerators];

// Copy the current table to the buffer
VERIFY(CopyAcceleratorTable(hAccelOld, pAccels, iNumAccelerators) == iNumAccelerators);

// Modify the pAccels array as required
...

// Destroy the current table resource...
VERIFY(DestroyAcceleratorTable(hAccelOld) == TRUE);

// ... create a new one, based on our modified table
m_hTerAcceleratorTable = CreateAcceleratorTable(pAccels, iNumAccelerators); 
ASSERT(m_hTerAcceleratorTable != NULL);

// Cleanup
delete[] pAccels;
```

Comment: If you can't get the resource ID, you can get the handle using HACCEL hAccelOld = ((CFrameWnd*)(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd))->m_hAccelTable;